# shell script to compare two files and print the line that contains common word?

Tags: shell, grep

let us consider two files, file 1 contains three words and file 2 contains some lines. i want the output that should contain the lines from file 2 that have words in file 1 and next 2 lines

File 1

```
EF-hand_motif
Ferritin
Manganese_catalase
```

File 2

```
a_1.out:The conserved site of Ferritin is found as: ['EFKEAFSL', 'EAELQDMI', 'EMIREADI']
a_1.out:Length of conserved site: 32
a_1.out:Position: 0-31
g_1.out:The conserved site of EF-hand_motif is found as: ['DADGNGTIDFPE', 'DKDGNGYISAAE']
g_1.out:Length of conserved site: 28
g_1.out:Position: 0-27
d_1.out:The conserved site of Hemerythrin is found as: ['ELRH']
d_1.out:Length of conserved site: 4
d_1.out:Position: 100-103
```

Wanted output format

```
a_1.out:The conserved site of Ferritin is found as: ['EFKEAFSL', 'EAELQDMI', 'EMIREADI']
a_1.out:Length of conserved site: 32
a_1.out:Position: 0-31
g_1.out:The conserved site of EF-hand_motif is found as: ['DADGNGTIDFPE', 'DKDGNGYISAAE']
g_1.out:Length of conserved site: 28
g_1.out:Position: 0-27
```

Answer (score 2):

using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ grep -Ff file1 -A 2 file2
a_1.out:The conserved site of Ferritin is found as: ['EFKEAFSL', 'EAELQDMI', 'EMIREADI']
a_1.out:Length of conserved site: 32
a_1.out:Position: 0-31
g_1.out:The conserved site of EF-hand_motif is found as: ['DADGNGTIDFPE', 'DKDGNGYISAAE']
g_1.out:Length of conserved site: 28
g_1.out:Position: 0-27
```

- `-F` means match fixed strings instead of regexps,
- `-f file` means read patterns to be matched from `file`,
- `-A n` means print `n` lines of trailing context after matching line.